# How in buildSrc use project() instead of const string, Gradle Dependency Management with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, buildsrc

I use const string in my project, like here: https://handstandsam.com/2018/02/11/kotlin-buildsrc-for-better-gradle-dependency-management.
In my build.gradle.kts my dependencies block looks like:

```
dependencies {
    compile(project(DepModule.cmn))
    compile(project(DepModule.logs))
   .......
}
```

How use in dependencies block `compile(DepModule.cmn)` instead of `compile(project(DepModule.cmn))`? And is it possible so?

Comment: Are `DepModule.cmn` and `DepModule.logs` strings for the project names?

Comment: @BjørnVester, yes, it's string, like: ":module:logs"

Comment: I don't know if this is possible. But a cool feature that is coming in Gradle 6.9 is built-in support for type-safe accessors like this. See [PR-14896](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/14896).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Kotlin in your `buildSrc`, you can write the following:

```
object DepModule {
    val DependencyHandler.cmn get() = project(":module:common")
}
```

and then access in `build.gradle.kts` like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile(DepModule.cmn)
}
```

I'm not sure if this trick with extension properties will work with Groovy.